# avoiding pixel compression in grid recognition

Tags: c#, image, grid, compression, pixel

Software takes an image as input (bmp, jpeg, whatever) with a white background and a black grid on it, I need to recognize grid propertys like Heigth, Width and cell size

This would be an easy job if the pixel color were sharp, but as we know due to compression it's not like that

I tried some normalizing algorithm in order to work with a pure black and white image but they are not 100% accurate, this the result using this simple function:

```
 public static Bitmap BlackWhite(Bitmap bmp)
    {


        Bitmap bw = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

        return bw;


    }
```

**before and after**

[image]

as you can see outline is not correct

I get better results using a slow home made function:

```
        public static Bitmap ColorSharp(Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        int i = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
        {

            for (y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(i, y);
                if (color.R <= 145 && color.G <= 145 && color.B <= 145)
                    bitmap.SetPixel(i, y, Color.Black);
                else
                    bitmap.SetPixel(i, y, Color.White);

            }
        }

        return bitmap;

    }
```

**but still not perfect**

[image]

i know it's probabily impossible to have a 100% accuracy, expecially with high compressed image, but do you have any idea how to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: You can weigh the brightness with the coordinates. Or, if all cells and all strokes have the same widths you can use an average. - Of course if the results are non-integer you will not be able to display them in a 1bit bitmap or else no antialiasing would have been necessary in the 1st place.. Which (aa) is what I think actually has happened rather than a compression artifact. To spell it out: Your example is missing the true 'before' version, most likely because there is none..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply Skeletonization or Thinning morphological operations to bitmap matrix. There are standard functions in OpenCV which will work fast.

Comment: mmmh, I don't think this is case
I have symbols inside most of the cells that later I need to recognise
What I need is to find the right grid outline thickness in order to discover each symbol

Comment: I see. You can take a look at example, where the algorithm of fining horizontal lines is explained. The same thing can be done to detect vertical lines. This will extract your grid and ignore symbols inside cells. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html